# Could not resolve dependency for renderiing plugin in Grails 3

Tags: grails, dependencies, rendering

I added rendering plugin as dependency in build.gradle for my grails 3 project as mentioned in https://grails.org/plugin/rendering

```
compile ":rendering:1.0.0"
```

When I execute 'gradle dependencies',it says failed. It did not give me any error message but it says failed when the dependencies are listed.

These are the default repositories generated with project

```
repositories {

    mavenLocal()

    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}
```

I tried even this way but did not work

```
compile "rendering:rendering:1.0.0"
```

Let me know if I am missing anything or the syntax is wrong.

Comment: `compile "org.grails.plugins:rendering:1.0.0"`

Comment: This did not work for me. Am I missing any repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 1.0.0 of `rendering` plugin is not compatible with Grails 3. Compatible version is `2.0.0-SNAPSHOT` and above.

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:rendering:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

in `build.gradle` [should be good with the repository that is currently present](http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/rendering/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/).

With Grails 2.*, yes you would need to use this repo: http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/rendering/1.0.0/.

```
maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins" }
```

Comment: This resolved the dependency issue, but I could not see any jar downloaded for rendering plugin. Is this expected? I tried to pdfRenderingService to generate pdf referring this example [http://www.icodeya.com/2012/09/grails-how-do-i-render-gsp-files-in-pdf.html]. Let me know If I have to create a bean for pdfRenderingService in resources.groovy.

Comment: You don't have to. If you can upload a sample app in github showcasing the problem, I will be glad to have a look.

Comment: <https://github.com/divya-gangidi/https---github.com-divya-gangidi-PrintDemoGit> I created the sample application here

Comment: I am getting this error when I execute run-app -> startup failed:
C:\Dev\Source\PrintDemoGit\grails-app\controllers\PrintCertController.groovy: -1
: The return type of java.lang.Object getPdfRenderingService() in PrintCertContr
oller is incompatible with grails.plugins.rendering.pdf.PdfRenderingService in g
rails.plugins.rendering.RenderingTrait
. At [-1:-1]  @ line -1, column -1.
1 error

Comment: You have to follow the documentaion http://gpc.github.io/rendering/guide/3.%20Rendering.html. In order to use the plugin the way you are using you have to use `renderPdf` as shown [here](http://gpc.github.io/rendering/guide/5.%20Rendering%20To%20The%20Response.html) instead of directly rendering from the service. The service returns bytes.

Comment: I tried the using the format mentioned in rendering document, still it did not work. The issue is 'pdfRenderingService' is not injecting into the controller. So when I access render method it is throwing me NPE.          Caused by NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method render() on null object
->>   32 | doCall    in PrintCertController.groovy

Comment: Did you run `gradlew build` or `grails compile` after adding the plugin dependency?

Comment: Yes i executed grails compile. Even grails run-app is executing with out any errors and application is build successful. I could view the application page. When I try to access the functionality to get pdf it is failing with NPE.

Answer (score 0):

We could resolve the dependency injection issue. There was some issue with the project we were working on.So, created a new project and it is working fine. Thankyou.

But we are still having issue with render method.We are calling the render method as below to get the generate the pdf. 'pdf' template is located atviews/render/_pdf.gsp

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
pdfRenderingService.render([template: '/render/pdf', model: [form:"Hello text"]],baos)
```

It is throwing the below exception. Can anyone let us know if we are calling render method in wrong way.

```
Line | Method
->> 1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    617 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by NullPointerException: null
->> 1337 | getPublicDeclaredMethods in java.beans.Introspector
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1197 | getTargetMethodInfo in     ''
|    426 | getBeanInfo in     ''
|    173 | getBeanInfo in     ''
|     31 | init . .  in     grails.plugins.rendering.document.RenderEnvironment
|     68 | with      in     ''
|     60 | with . .  in     ''
|     65 | generateXhtml in         grails.plugins.rendering.document.XhtmlDocumentService
|     35 | createDocument in     ''
|     36 | render    in grails.plugins.rendering.RenderingService
|     43 | buildPdf  in RenderController.groovy
```